# Changing innodb_log_file_size in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am a starter in Linux and am hence new to all this. Please take my noob mistakes kindly if there are any.
So I am installing OTRS in Linux for which I have to change the innodb_log_file_size to 512M

So I did the following but have been unsuccessful to change the log_file_size.

- Set GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown to 1
- Ensured that shutdown was completed using log file (It did indeed, saw a line which said Shutdown complete)
- Moved the following files to home

> logfile0 & logfile1 from cd /var/lib/mysql

- Nano edited the my.cnf in `

> /etc/mysql/my.cnf

I added the following line under

```
 [mysqldump] 
 inno_db_log_file_size = 512M
```

Saved and closed the .cnf file and restarted mysql server using

> /etc/init.d/mysql start

I then checked the error log file and found that the logfile0 & logfile1 got recreated but got recreated with 5MB size again

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. I am guessing that I am not adding the `inno_db_log_file_size = 512M` in the right place.

**P.S:** There was no inno_db_log_file_size line before I added it.

Thanks in advance.

`

Answer (score 1):

The config option is `innodb_log_file_size` or `innodb-log-file-size` (`-` and `_` are both valid), but not `inno_db_log_file_size`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is what I added. I figured out where to write the line.

The above was just a typo. Thanks for looking into it.:)

I solved it myself. Cheers.

Comment: So, how did you fix it?